# Positive integral on every interval implies positive almost everywhere if continuous?

Tags: analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R_+$ is continuous. I want to claim the following:

If $$0\le a < b \le 1\implies \int_a^b f(x) dx > 0,$$ then $$f(x) > 0 \quad  \text{a.e. on } [0,1].$$

I know that if $f$ isn't continuous then couterexamples to the above exist. But I am not able to see how to prove the property I ask with continuity.

Thanks.

Comment: This is false. There is a continuous function which is $0$ on a Cantor set of positive mesaure for which the hypothesis is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be  Cantor set of positive measure. For each of the intervals removed in the construction of $C$ let $f$ be $0$ at the end points and strictly positive  inside the interval. Putting these together gives a counter-example to your claim since any open interval $(a,b)$ contains points not in $C$ (and $f(x)>0$ at such points).

Comment: Thanks! This is great.